# makefile iteration and retrieving the filename

Tags: makefile, iteration, filenames

In a makefile, I am trying to iterate through c files and use the path as well as the filename.
For example for /dir/dir2/file.c
I want to execute "cc /dir/dir2/file.c -o file"
I do not understand why basename and patsubst do not work. It just shows me the path as is.
Can anyone please help?

```
test_files := Test/src/test_*.c

compile_tests:
    @for f in $(test_filenames); do \
        echo ">>> $(basename $(patsubst %.c, %, $$f ))";\
    done
```

Comment: Please be careful when showing examples to show ones you actually tried.  In the above you're using `test_files` and `test_filenames` which can confuse people as to what's really wrong.

Comment: It would help if we knew what you were actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix and match make functions with shell operations.  Make will fully expand all the variables and functions first, then it passes the result of the expansion to the shell and the shell runs it as a script.

You are trying to use a make function inside a shell loop, but the make function is expanded first, then the loop will run on the results.  The basename and patsubst run on the literal string `$f`, which doesn't have any pathname and does not match the `%.c` pattern, so those functions have no effect.

If you want to do it this way you must use 100% shell operations, or else modify the variable before the shell gets it like this:

```
test_filenames := $(wildcard Test/src/test_*.c)

compile_tests:
        @for f in $(basename $(patsubst %.c,%,$(test_filenames))); do \
            echo ">>> $$f";\
        done
```

ETA: if you want to do it all in the shell, you can use:

```
test_filenames := $(wildcard Test/src/test_*.c)

compile_tests:
        @for f in $(test_filenames); do \
            echo ">>> $$(basename $$f .c)";\
        done
```

Or, perhaps more clearly:

```
test_filenames := $(wildcard Test/src/test_*.c)

compile_tests:
        @for f in $(test_filenames); do \
            echo ">>> `basename $$f .c`";\
        done
```

Comment: but as I mentioned, I need both the source path and the filenames as the output so I cannot use the make command. I need to do it %100 in bash as you say, but bash operations on $$f do not work. I've tried the basename operation of bash for example: echo ">>> $(basename $$f .c)"; still does not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think this would do it:  @for f in $(test_files); do \
  $(CC) $(LINKFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(MY_LIBS) $$f -o $(BUILD_BIN_DIR)$$(basename $$f .c);\
 done

Comment: The method in your comment doesn't work because you are trying to use the `$()` form of backticks, but if you do that you have to escape the `$` so make doesn't try to expand it, like: `echo ">>> $$(basename $$f.c)"`